# Magento 2.2.6 reindex not finishing Catalog Search CLI Putty crashing

Tags: magento2.2, apache, elasticsearch

Apache 2.4 Linux Centos

store has 25,000 sku

I am trying to reindex Magento 2.2.6 site with elasticsearch 5.1 running

when I try to run full reindex it takes a long time when it reaches

php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

then after about 1 hour or so it crashes the Putty CLI

Tried to reindex manually by running  on its own but same issue is happening
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext

Any ideas please and what settings should I be looking at on the server too

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try to reindex all?

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

so without --catalogsearch_fulltext

If it is not working well, try to deactivate module and try again;

> php bin/magento module:disable elasticsearch

Dont forget to run following commands after changes;

1. bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
4. bin/magento cache:clean
5. bin/magento cache:flush
6. bin/magento indexer:reindex

Also make sure that your cache is cleared. If not, clear it manually:

> rm -rf

```
var/cache/
var/page_cache/
generated/code/
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but already run all of these